# "window.openDatabase is not a function" error in chrome app

Tags: html, sqlite, google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-app

When i run my index.html from chrome browser everything works fine but after i created a chrome app from the same files and tried to run the app i get "window.openDatabase is not a function" error.Did i miss something? I've heard that WEBsql is being depreciated but if that's the problem then why is it working on my browser?The only change i made to the folder with my html/js/css files in order to create the chrome app was adding a manifest and a background.js,i also changed window.localstorage with chrome.storage.local

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has refused to support it in apps.

> Given that WebSQL is deprecated, it's extremely unlikely that we'd expose the API in new contexts.

It has been noted that you can workaround by using it inside a [webview](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview). Here is the [relevant issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=339579).

Comment: Thank you for your help,the webview solution is perfect for my app!